# Java 8 lambda expression bytecode consistency

Tags: java, java-8, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I've been digging through Java lambda expression bytecode as compiled by my OpenJDK compiler, and I'm wondering, can lambda expression bytecode vary by compiler/runtime? I'd like to know that my inspection logic will work across platforms, or not.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to inspect? Note in particular that if the Groovy 3 compiler gets off the ground, with its support for Java 8-style lambdas, it's likely to emit *significantly* different bytecode.

Comment: openjdk's javac is not the only java compiler in existence, ecj is a commonly used alternative for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can lambda expression bytecode vary by compiler/runtime?

In theory yes.  The JLS does NOT specify that particular bytecodes / sequences must be generated.

You would need to check the bytecodes emitted by existing Java 8 & Java 9 compilers to see how much they differ.  (And that doesn't tell you about compilers / versions that are yet to be written!)

> I'd like to know that my inspection logic will work across platforms, or not.

The solution should be to build a comprehensive set of test cases and run them against the code produced by all Java compilers that you want to support.

In short: test it.